# Creating nested tables using div

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how to create the below structure using div
[image]

Comment: you have to try something we are not here to write a code for you.

Comment: You can do that using tables much easily. If you are using DIVs then it might become a messy code.

Comment: if it really is a table of content go for tables, but otherwise don't

Comment: Post your code what you tried already?

Comment: Without real textual content and images, no way to tell you if there are (table) headers, headings, etc

Answer (score 5):

If you need a table, use a table. Just because tables shouldn't be used for layout, it doesn't mean they can't be used anywhere. Using divs for this purpose will give you lots of unmanageable and messy code.

Comment: yes i have seen many people that are using div to show tabular data and at the end it becomes a messy code.

Comment: True the code will be little unmanageable as this is not a layout for the page instead i need this as layout for my list view items, if i will use nested tables for this page will be heavy....any help would be great.

Comment: Actually, tables can be very concise. It's a common misconception that tables increase file size. I've seen many div workarounds that have many many lines of superfluous code.